# I want to null the value of ng-model="data.closingDay ,null after I seleced checkbox

Tags: angularjs

```
  <md-input-container >
     <label>Days</label> 
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="all">

    <md-select ng-model="data.closingDay" multiple ng-disabled="all">

    <md-optgroup label="days">       
    <md-option ng-value="day"  ng-repeat="day in days">{{day}}</md-option>

    </md-optgroup>
    </md-select>
 </md-input-container >
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QMN9.jpg)

[image]

when a user first selected the days after that select the checkbox the model of days still keep the value of days thats the problem

Comment: Thanks so much Omar Einea..Now it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by adding something like this to your checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="data.closingDay = null">
```

Re-posting for future viewers.